# How to read multiple sub row values from XML using XDocument and Dictionary VB.net 2008

Tags: xml, vb.net, parsing, linq-to-xml

How do you parse repeating XML sub row values in VB.net (2008) using XDocument, and Dictionary. In the code below I am able to read everything down to first row of userGroup..
Hide   Copy Code

I get all the values for the FIRST row:

> "XX1" "MAIN GROUP" "111" "NORMAL" "/AAA/XX1/NANA"

I don't know how to loop through the remaining userGroup rows to get the rest of the values. 
I need ALL of the values from ALL of the rows starting with userGroup.

```
<userGroup id="XX1" title="MAIN GROUP" orgCode="111" type="NORMAL" fullPath="/AAA/XX1/NANA"/>
<userGroup id="ABC" title="Test Group1" orgCode="ABC-123" type="NORMAL" fullPath="/ABC/"/>
<userGroup id="XX2" title="Test Group2" orgCode="QRX-567" type="NORMAL" fullPath="/AAA/XX2/"/>
<userGroup id="XX5" title="Test Group3" orgCode="BB1" type="NORMAL" fullPath="/AAA/XX5/BB1"/>
```

There could be 1 to many userGroup rows. 
My goals is to be able to read all values and store them into local variables.

Example: Reading all orgCode values from userGroup row(s) and storing them concatenated in a local string variable.

strLocal_VARIABLE_All_orgCodes = "111, ABC-123, QRX-567, BB1"

Sample Code:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Dim result = ParseXML()
    For Each key1 In result.Keys
        Console.WriteLine(key1 & " --> " & result(key1))
    Next
End Sub

Function ParseXML() As Dictionary(Of String, String)

        Dim parseValues = New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        Dim doc As XDocument = <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                               <sslms status="ok" time="0">
                                   <user username="123456" activated="true" userRole="END_USER" isCustomUser="false" selfReg="false" regDate="2015-01-17T20:08:30Z" siteLanguage="en-US" searchLanguage="en">
                                       <profileFieldValues>
                                           <fieldValue id="_sys_firstname">
                                               <value>John</value>
                                           </fieldValue>
                                           <fieldValue id="_sys_lastname">
                                               <value>Doe</value>
                                           </fieldValue>
                                           <fieldValue id="_sys_emailaddress">
                                               <value>JDoe@someplace.net</value>
                                           </fieldValue>
                                           <fieldValue id="_sys_display_first_name">
                                               <value>John</value>
                                           </fieldValue>
                                           <fieldValue id="_sys_display_last_name">
                                               <value>Doe</value>
                                           </fieldValue>
                                           <fieldValue id="_sys_location">
                                               <value/>
                                           </fieldValue>
                                           <fieldValue id="_sys_image_url">
                                               <value/>
                                           </fieldValue>
                                           <fieldValue id="ccnumber">
                                               <value>NO</value>
                                           </fieldValue>
                                       </profileFieldValues>
                                       <userGroup id="XX1" title="MAIN GROUP" orgCode="111" type="NORMAL" fullPath="/AAA/XX1/NANA"/>
                                       <userGroup id="ABC" title="Test Group1" orgCode="ABC-123" type="NORMAL" fullPath="/ABC/"/>
                                       <userGroup id="XX2" title="Test Group2" orgCode="QRX-567" type="NORMAL" fullPath="/AAA/XX2/"/>
                                       <userGroup id="XX5" title="Test Group3" orgCode="BB1" type="NORMAL" fullPath="/AAA/XX5/BB1"/>
                                   </user>
                               </sslms>

        For Each attr In doc.Element("sslms").Attributes()
            parseValues.Add("sslms_" & attr.Name.ToString, attr.Value)
        Next

        For Each attr In doc.Element("sslms").Element("user").Attributes()
            parseValues.Add("user_" & attr.Name.ToString, attr.Value)
        Next

        For Each ele In doc.Element("sslms").Element("user").Element("profileFieldValues").Elements("fieldValue")
            parseValues.Add(ele.Attributes.First.Value.ToString, ele.Element("value").Value)
        Next

        For Each attr In doc.Element("sslms").Element("user").Element("userGroup").Attributes()
            parseValues.Add("userGroup_" & attr.Name.ToString, attr.Value)
        Next

        Return parseValues

    End Function
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `GroupBy()` and `String.Join()` to get concatenated value of all attributes with the same name :

```
For Each attr In doc.Element("sslms").
                     Element("user").
                     Elements("userGroup").
                     Attributes().
                     GroupBy(Function(x) x.Name.ToString())
    parseValues.Add("userGroup_" & attr.Key, String.Join(",", attr.Select(Function(x) x.Value)))
Next
```

Relevant part of the output :

```
userGroup_id --> XX1,ABC,XX2,XX5
userGroup_title --> MAIN GROUP,Test Group1,Test Group2,Test Group3
userGroup_orgCode --> 111,ABC-123,QRX-567,BB1
userGroup_type --> NORMAL,NORMAL,NORMAL,NORMAL
userGroup_fullPath --> /AAA/XX1/NANA,/ABC/,/AAA/XX2/,/AAA/XX5/BB1
```